# k fold cross validation model assessment

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have been reading about the technique of k-fold cross validation and I came through [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/cross_validation.html):

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
>>> scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(
...    clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
...
>>> scores                                              
array([ 0.96...,  1.  ...,  0.96...,  0.96...,  1.        ])
```

The mean score and the standard deviation of the score estimate are given by:

```
>>>
>>> print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)
```

According to [this source](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/cross-validation-and-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-for-dummies/) it says

> When you perform k-fold CV, you get k different estimates of your
>   model’s error- say e_1, e_2, e_3, ..., e_k. Since each e_i is an error
>   estimate, it should ideally be zero.
>
> To check out you model’s bias, find out the mean of all the e_i's. If
>   this value is low, it basically means that your model gives low error
>   on an average– indirectly ensuring that your model’s notions about the
>   data are accurate enough.

According to the example of the SVM with the iris dataset, it gives a mean of 0.98, so does this mean that our model is not flexible enough?

Comment: 0.98 means 98% accuracy, which is 2% error, doesn't sound bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Wordpress site you link to refers to "error" whereas the code you are using is calculating `accuracy`, so higher values are better for you.
2. The mean accuracy is 0.98. Is it good? I can't say because it can only be judged relative to a benchmark.
3. When doing cross-validation, you are mainly interested in the stability of your classifier, not the mean accuracy. Cross-validation asks essentially: "how well does my classifier perform across different parts of my dataset?" and you use the results to answer: "how well will my classifier perform on data it has not seen before?" Therefore, you really need to look at the standard deviation of you accuracy scores.

`Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)`

Your results show that you have 95% confidence that the mean accuracy will be between 0.95 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

So I think your question is a misunderstanding of what k-fold is for. Thought I would explain a couple things about it.

It's used in machine learning for when you have a smaller sample size and you need to be able to test how accurate it is. K-fold splits your data into k different tests. So say it was 5, its 20% for testing, 80% for training, and which 20% is tested for is switched each test, same with which 80% is trained for. This is useful when you are worried about a bias because of small amounts of data.

The accuracy you get back is how accurate on average across the k tests it was able to identify what you were looking for, in this case which iris was correctly identified.

```
0.98% is quite a decent number so your model is fine. Thats an error rate of 0.02 
which is close to the 0 of the goal, as it is unlikely to ever hit 0.
```